# How to specify contextroot of in the app-deployer ant task when using ant to deploy a Worklight app

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight Knowledge Center has the following documentation for using ant to deploy an app to Worklight server:

```
<app-deployer deployable="app.wlapp"
    worklightServerHost="http://server-address:port/contextroot" 
    userName="username" password="password" />
```

But it doesn't provide any detail on how to specify contextroot. So I tried the following but none of them work:

```
worklightServerHost="http://localhost:9080"
worklightServerHost="http://localhost:9080/worklight"
```

How can contextroot be specified?

Comment: A few questions:  1) What version of Worklight are you using?;  2) What is the application's context root - is it actually "/worklight"?;  3) What kind of security test is protecting the Worklight Console - are you just using the single identity login module, or something more involved (such as LDAP)?

Answer (score 0):

The context root by default is your Worklight project's name. So if you project is called MyProject, that's your context root. Change it to that.

Keeping the project name as-is, but using another for the deployment is set-up I believe in the server.xml file.